# Pandas - No Quote Character saved to file

Tags: pandas, quote

I am having a difficult time trying to get any "Quote" Character to print out using to_csv function in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd 
final = pd.DataFrame(dataset.loc[::])
final.to_csv(r'c:\temp\temp2.dat', doublequote=True, mode='w',
sep='\x14', quotechar='\xFE', index=False)
print (final)
```

I have tried various options without success, I am not sure what i am missing.   Wondering igf anyone can point me in the right direction.  thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Finally!  it appears the documentation has changed or it not updated on the this.   adding the option of **quoting=1**  cures the issues. apparently, **quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL** no longer works.

the complete command is

```
import pandas as pd
final = pd.DataFrame(dataset.loc[::])
final.to_csv(r'c:\temp\temp2.dat', index=False, doublequote=True,sep='\x14', quoting=1, quotechar='\xFE')
print (final)
```